# UDP received datapackets but prints out funny results

Tags: java, network-programming, udp

I am doing a simple UDP file.txt transfer from sender to receiver. It arrived as prompt.. BUT, when I print the content some came out correctly, but some were mashed up with previous words received on the receiver end.

What I mean: 
The text file has the content ALL IN ONE SENTENCE as:

***day after day, week after week passed away on my return to Geneva;***

eg on the receiver side:

***day 
after 
day,r
weekr
after
weekr
passed
awayed
onayed
myayed 
return
toturn
Geneva***

code for this is:

```
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[9999]; 
        DatagramSocket listenSocket = new DatagramSocket(5001, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1")); 
    while(true) {   
        DatagramPacket segment = new DatagramPacket(byteArray, byteArray.length); 
        listenSocket.receive(segment); 
        ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(segment.getData()); 
        int data = byteIn.read(); 
        if(data == -1) { 
        //break; 
        } else { 
           System.out.println("Got: " + new String(segment.getData()));
        }
```

Yes, TCP would have been a more better option but I need help on why this happens in this case. I hope you all can give me insight to this problem.

Comment: UDP does not guarantee correct order and duplicate protection. If you need this you have to use TCP or implement all these services yourself on top of UDP.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to blank the buffer after first using it - so if a consecutive receive gets less data, than a previous, you will re-read some of the old data.

Comment: Alrighty, I FINALLY got it working right after I saw your response. 
What I did was simply move the buffer INSIDE the while loop that way it clears the previous words stored.

Comment: While this solves your problem, it is inefficient: You will allocated and GC it much too often. Consider blanking it or using the receive length to truncate.

Comment: that is very true point there. Right i will hunt down the java method for this.

Comment: Have you tried simply setting the first 5 bytes of the array to 0 ?